# Need a Detail Info About (Next) in Middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, middleware

How does Next work in Middleware how does it know whether to allow a request through one pipeline to another? and how does it block when it feels the request is not proper or missing? how can I know in-depth working of Middleware, Pipeline, and traversal from one pipeline to other?

Basically, there are Two Items where I got stuck

First in Authorization of API actions.
While giving the wrong or invalid Token to API and calling some action I always found that my Default/Custom Middleware used to block or stop render/debugging further to the Controller Page like how it does I didn't know the concept of blocking/stopping.

The second is with CORS.
I have allowed my App endpoint into API but still, I was getting an error on the Application Side was CORs and from Default Middleware it was rejecting me to go ahead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In your Middle Ware, You need to call next.Invoke(context) or await next(context) to pass the request to the next middle ware,   If an unhandled exception is thrown within a middleware component, it will propagate up the call stack, and the middleware pipeline's execution will be halted. Please make your question fucose on one specific point